What do we mean by Uniqueness in Ordinary Differential Equations?
According to Piccard-Lindelof Theorem, there exists a solution for every Initial Value Problem (under some conditions like Lipschitz, etc.) and that solution is unique. However, when we say that the solution is unique, we mean that it is unique GIVEN some interval, right?
Because if not suppose f: (1,2) --> R is a solution, then g: (1.5,2) ---> R is also a solution and so the solution would not be unique.

If you look at the full specification of the theorem, it states that there exists an interval on which there is a unique solution, so yes it does also specify a domain.

Maybe a counter-example of uniqueness would improve the concept: Norton's Dome example

An IVP $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$ is said to be uniquely solvable if 1. it has a solution and 2. if $y_1:I_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $y_2:I_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are solutions then $y_1=y_2$ on $I_1\cap I_2$.
